# Create a row array B, consisting of substrings of elements of array A

Tags: c#

An array of strings A is given. Each element consists of the clients surname and name. Create a row array B, consisting of substrings of elements of array A and
containing only clients names.

My code doesn't work.
I enter Donna Paulson, Jhon Elliot, and i get Donna, Elliot.
It needs to be Paulson, Elliot, because only names are needed

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Clients
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] A = new string[m];
            string[] B = new string[m];

            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"A[{i}]= ");
                A[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
           for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
                string[] text = A[i].Split(' ');
                B[i] = text[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(B[i]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *It's not working* is not a sufficient problem description, please add more details. See [this for reference](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: `text[i]` should be either `text[0]` or `text[1]` depending on whether the surname is displayed first or second. Do note, however, that since you're not validating the user input, there's no guarantee that it will contain a space character, so you might still end up with an IndexOutOfRangeException at some point if you use `text[1]`.

Comment: Please provide some *examples* of initil data and the desired output.

Comment: Please give some strings as examples like
These are my strings "Donna Paulson", "Jhon Elliot"...
What I want is this "Paulson", "Elliot".

Comment: Relevant [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)